# Microsoft Excel 2007 - Slow Sheet Response (Even in Safe Mode)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am currently having issues with an excel file. I am opening a large file with multiple pages/books inside and excel starts to lag, when I click a cell it takes a couple of seconds for the cell to be highlighted and then to enter the field it also lags. I have tired turning off Auto Calculations but when I start Excel in Safe Mode it works for a bit then slows down again. The only issue is that this is an IT issue and we do not want to have the end user starting up Excel in Safe Mode every time.

What I want to figure out is what does Safe Mode disable. I have checked the add-in's and have found nothing, I checked everywhere both in excel and while excel is in safe mode. What is causing my large excel file to lag? Also take note that the file is under 400Mb.

Comment: Does this happen on more than one machine? Are there macros? Have you tried copying the data to a new book?

Comment: I happens on multiple machines. The file is on a shared drive and is accessed by multiple users. We have checked the connections on all the computers that access the drive and that is not the issue. All Macros and Add-Ins are disabled. And I have not tired that, I will give it a shot and get back to you.

Comment: @Raystafarian, I tried copying over all the data an books and the sheet still slows down or comes to a halt. I have noticed in the resource monitor that when I click a cell, input a value (or new value) the CPU usage maxes out. There is a slight performance increase and decrease in lag time but the sheet still freezes when the application is set on High Priority through the task manager but that is only a short term solution.

Comment: I have also noticed that when I remove formatting the sheet works just fine.

Comment: Are there a lot of volatile formulas?

Comment: No. There were only a couple of formulas. The issue was that one column had about 10 rules for conditional formatting and that was causing the performance of the sheet to come to a hault.

Answer (score 2):

One of the columns on every sheet had about 10 rules pertaining to Conditional Formatting which in turn caused the slowdown of the sheet.

Comment: That'll do it, glad you figured it out and shared the solution.

Comment: For sure and thank you again! Turns out that this sheet has been troubling the end users who access it for years, and it's my first week on the job haha!